# Error "constructor ResourceDto in class ResourceDto cannot be applied to given types" while mapping with enum in the constructor

Tags: java, kotlin, mapstruct

I have an issue with MapStruct when converting entity class into the DTO. This issue occur only when I have enum in the DTO's constructor.

Here is my DTO class

```
class ResourceDto(
    val id: Long,
    val name: String,
    val status: ResourceStatus,
    val location: LocationDto,
)
```

and error that I am getting

> constructor ResourceDto in class ResourceDto cannot be applied to given types;
> ResourceDto resourceDto = new ResourceDto();
> ^
> required: long,String,ResourceStatus,LocationDto
> found: no arguments
> reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

When I remove the enum `ResourceStatus` from the constructor, it works as expected.
Do you have any suggestion, why is this happening?